# How to get code from a Php native function?

Tags: php

Most of the php functions are written in c, there are several functions like `array_map`, `list`, ... internally all of them have their code, I think the use foreach, compare string, and so  forth.

Now for a project, I need to get the code of one of this functions. I think if I know the way to get any function native code, it doesn't really matter which function is, but in my case I need the code of `DOMDocument::query`.

Comment: `DOMDocument` has no method named `query`. I guess you mean `DOMXPath::query`?

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/dom/xpath.c